# grunt uglify keep minified file in same folder as of src

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-uglify

I have application code structure where js files are distributed in multiple folders. Can we create grunt uglify task so that minified files will be put in same folder as of src or max it should be put under /dist under same folder as of src and this will be done recursively scanning all src js files in application.

In html we have to include all js files but want to keep normal js for development and debugging purpose and minified while testing and deployment. Do it have any better option so I do not have to change main.html each time.

```
  uglify: {
        options: {
            report: 'min',
            mangle: false
        },
        controllers: {
            files: {
                'src/main/webapp/app/controllers/dist/controllers.min.js': ['src/main/webapp/app/controllers/*.js', '!src/main/webapp/app/controllers/dist/*.js']
            }
        }
    }
```

This is uglify task but i want it to recursively look in all folders and sub folders in src/main/webapp/app/ for *.js file and create *.min.js in same location.

Comment: Please post your Gruntfile.js

Comment: updated question with uglify task.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
uglify: {
        options: {
            report: 'min',
            mangle: false,
            compress: {},
            banner: '/* minified JS file */'
        },
        js: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                src: ['src/main/webapp/app/**/*.js', '!src/main/webapp/app/**/*.min.js'],
                ext: '.min.js'
            }]
        }
    }
```

This will uglify looking into src recursively for *.js and make minified copy in  same directory as of source .js file.